# Reason for versioning of dll

Tags: c++

If a dll which is exposing some functions through abstract base class,added some new functions in it.
Will it break the compatibility with the applications using this dll.
if yes,Why?
if no, Why?
How newly introduced functions will stored in vtable of the interface.
Also it is always necessary to maintain the versions of the dll.

Comment: It won't break anything if you didn't disturb anything existing and didn't add or subtract any virtual functions in the exposed interface.

Comment: If I add a virtual function at the end of the file, will it break the compatibility or it just append the added function at the end of vtable?